# Getting nothing from Google Calendar API

Tags: .net, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

Using a Google service account, I'm trying to get CalendarLists and Events from a domain. Neither one works. All I get is an JSON exception saying:

```
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

which I would translate to no data retrieved.

Is there any problem with Google Calendar API and service accounts?

Example code:

```
var req = CalendarService.CalendarList.List();
try
{
    var list = req.Execute();
    return list;
}
catch { }
```

or (with a valid email at the domain)

```
var req = CalendarService.Events.List("x@y.com");
var test = req.Execute();
var x = test.Items;
```

and the service is created by:

```
var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(settings.ServiceAccountEmail)
{
    Scopes = new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
    User = string.Format("{0}@{1}", settings.AdminUsername, settings.Domain)
}.FromCertificate(settings.Certificate.Certificate));

return new CalendarService((new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "DotDash Fix",
}));
```

At least all other services I have implemented work. If I log on with the admin user that is connected to the service account, I can see the calendars perfectly fine.

Comment: 1) Can you attach fiddler tracing or the exact request and response. 2) I would also recommend doing the same requests with regular flow (not service account). 3) Are you sure that you are using the right p12 file? 4) Consider attaching the exception's stacktrace.

Comment: @peleyal 1) I will do that (just not much time today). 2) That would require some implementation, but I could do it as a second debugging measure. 3) Yes I'm sure. Admin Directory calls work just fine. 4) Will be considered ;)

Thanks!

Comment: 2) It should be easy - read out OAuth2 wiki page for more information. Let me know if I can help. Good luck!